# Backend/frontend architecture to get better website performance

Tags: architecture, frontend, backend

I'm seeking further guidance regarding the backend/frontend architecture of my portfolio assets tracking app.

In this project, I am in the process of developing both the backend and frontend components. The cornerstone of the application is the "Transaction" model, which encompasses all the crucial information concerning the types and values of my assets. The primary objective is to utilize this model for comprehensive calculations.

On the frontend, I intend to display assets categorized by type, paginated transactions, portfolio value, specific asset values, and more.

Presently, I find myself at a crossroads:

1. Should I retrieve all "transaction" data from the backend, store it in local storage or cache, and perform calculations on the frontend (e.g., asset values) to minimize the frequency of requests?
2. Or maybe is it preferable to make specific requests as required? This would entail repetitive GET requests, such as for paginated transaction views, obtaining all transactions for portfolio valuation, and similar requests to calculate stock values.
   (a lot of repeated GETs)
3. Alternatively, would it be advisable to expand the backend by creating additional endpoints like "portfolio value" and "stocks value"? These values would be calculated upon the insertion of new transactions into the database and stored as separate columns. Subsequently, the frontend could simply request the latest "portfolio value," "stocks value," etc. In this scenario, the only resource-intensive request would be for reviewing all transactions (with pagination), while obtaining all transactions wouldn't be necessary unless specifically desired.
   In this case I would have some repeated data in database (I mean e.g. sum of transactions value) but database would not be queried so many times.
4. Building upon the third option. In this setup, the database would store a "transaction" table, with calculations being executed on backend side just before responding to specific requests. And here - it will be for sure many database queries and some computing power needed on backend side.

Which is the best option?
While option 3/4 seems promising, I am open to exploring alternative approaches.

Are there any compelling reasons to consider options 1 or 2 over 3/4? If so, do you have any examples?

Is it recommended to use 3 over 4? If so, in which scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic distributed cache question.  All of your options are examples of caching at different levels of granularity and at different distances from the transactional records.  Unfortunately there is not a "right" answer, each answer has tradeoffs.

In general, the further you get from the source records, the more efficient your cache is, but the more expensive that cache is to expire.  For example, caching the data in the browser is the most efficient, but it is hardest to detect an expiration (you have to round-trip to the server and ask the source database what's out of date).  Caching inside the database (pre-computed transaction values) is very efficient for checking for staleness, but costs more to retrieve.

Similarly, the coarser your cache (bigger chunks) the faster it will perform, at the downside of having less re-usability and a bigger hit when it does miss.  For example, the most coarse is full-page HTML.  However any little change (date ranges, filters, pagination, etc) will make that page invalid and require more processing to rebuild everything.  Fine-grained caching (individual database records) means that you still have to do all the work to assemble/calculate values, but will result in far more re-use because only expired records need to be retrieved/recalculated.

In general this becomes a hierarchy of caching, and expiring it when something changes is a convoluted processes. One thing to keep in mind, respect the work that has come before you.  Use pre-existing cache solutions, don't invent re-invent the wheel, your problems are not unique (and very smart people have already solved them).  Use write-through caching servers (look at things like memcached or redis).  And especially use HTTP cache to the fullest extent possible.  Cache-control headers are very powerful, and are supported at many layers of the internet to make your life easier.  A restful interface the fully supports HTTP cache-control is a beautiful thing to work with.